# C# BinarySerialize into different class name with different superclass

Tags: c#, serialization

I originally have a class like this

```
class Y : SuperClass
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
}
```

I have never use anything from SuperClass, so I decided to refractor my code into the new :

```
class Z
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
}
```

You can see that Z have exactly the same serialized data.

Now I already have many of Y:SuperClass data serialized into binary files, so I would like to migrate all of them into class Z one and re-serialize it.

I can load those files back into an instances of class Y:SuperClass but how can I then serialize them into class Z? Note that the real one contains many variables that I could not simply do `z.a = y.a; z.b = y.b; ...` for all of them. I wish there are more automatic ways of converting to class which you are sure the variable names match, like reflection or maybe something simpler. Thank you.

Comment: What type of serialization are you using?  If binary you will need to write your own parsing logic, if XML this will just work.

Comment: Sounds like you need to deserialize to `Y`, then map to `Z`.  There are libraries for doing that type of mapping like Automapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize to another type by utilizing the class: 
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder

The method is explained here in Advanced Binary Serialization section:

https://www.codeproject.com/kb/cs/drawwithmouse.aspx#AdvancedBinarySerialization%3aDeserializinganObjectIntoaDifferentTypeThantheOneItwasSerializedInto9